# Moment-determinacy in multivariate case

Tags: probability, analyticity, characteristic-functions

Let $X$ be a random vector with probability density $p$.

In the scalar case I have learned that if the characteristic function of $X$ is real analytic, then all moments exist and $p$ is determined by the moments.

Is this also true in the multivariate case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  The characteristic function $\phi(s) = {\mathbb E}[\exp(i s\cdot X)]$ is the complex conjugate of the Fourier transform of the density, and Fourier transform is one-to-one on $L^1$.  If it's real analytic, $\phi(s)$ is determined by the coefficients of its series expansion at $s=0$, which are the moments.